# Error when trying to encode

Tags: python, file, lzw

Why can't I use `sourcecode = "myFile.txt" f = open(sourcecode, mode='rb')` to open my file and compress it? This is all pretty new to me. I would be glad if some of you could give me some advice on how to solve the problem.

```
def compress(uncompressed):
    """Compress a string to a list of output symbols."""

    sourcecode = "myFile.txt"
    f = open(sourcecode, mode='rb')   

    # Build the dictionary.
    dict_size = 256
    dictionary = dict((chr(i), chr(i)) for i in xrange(dict_size))
    # in Python 3: dictionary = {chr(i): chr(i) for i in range(dict_size)}

    w = ""
    result = []
    for c in uncompressed:
        wc = w + c
        if wc in dictionary:
            w = wc
        else:
            result.append(dictionary[w])
            # Add wc to the dictionary.
            dictionary[wc] = dict_size
            dict_size += 1
            w = c

    # Output the code for w.
    if w:
        result.append(dictionary[w])
    return result



def decompress(compressed):
    """Decompress a list of output ks to a string."""

    # Build the dictionary.
    dict_size = 256
    dictionary = dict((chr(i), chr(i)) for i in xrange(dict_size))
    # in Python 3: dictionary = {chr(i): chr(i) for i in range(dict_size)}

    w = result = compressed.pop(0)
    for k in compressed:
        if k in dictionary:
            entry = dictionary[k]
        elif k == dict_size:
            entry = w + w[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Bad compressed k: %s' % k)
        result += entry

        # Add w+entry[0] to the dictionary.
        dictionary[dict_size] = w + entry[0]
        dict_size += 1

        w = entry
    return result

compressed = compress(f)
print (compressed)
decompressed = decompress(compressed)
print (decompressed)
```

I found this code at: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Python

Comment: What is the problem? What error does python give you when you try to open the file? Could it be the problem that you don't close the file at the end of `compress`?

Comment: Do you get an error while opening file? Could you post it here? Also you don't seem to call f.read() or f.write() anywhere, did you forget some other important piece?

Comment: File "/Users/Har/LZW2.py", line 57, in <module>
  compressed = compress(d)

NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: The code in the link makes sense. Your modifications doesn't make any sense. There's no need to open the file inside the `compress` method. Read the file first, and then pass the content to `compress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the fact that you open the file inside the `compress` function. That means that `f` is not visible outside the function, and therefore calling `compress(f)` will give you an error that it does not find `f`. The correct syntax would be to move the lines `sourcecode = "myFile.txt"` and `f = open(sourcecode, mode='rb')` there, so that you have:

```
sourcecode = "myFile.txt"
f = open(sourcecode, mode='rb') 
compressed = compress(f.read())
f.close() # don't forget to close open files
```

Notice the `f.read()` when calling `compress`. `f` by itself is a file descriptor, `f.read()` is the one that returns the contents of the file as a string to be given as an argument to `compress()`

Comment: Adding print (compressed) between compressed = compress(f.read()) and f.close() prints just a pair of empty brackers.

Comment: does 'myFile.txt' exist in working directory? What are the contents of this file?

Comment: Yes, somehow while I've been trying to get this working I've managed to empty the file. Found out that is was blank.